# datetime.now() is not setting current date

Tags: python, python-datetime

I would like to use datetime library to get current date -7 days.

I started with the following incorrect code

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from datetime import  datetime, timedelta

class ActivityCount(ndb.Model):
    last_login_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(default=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=-7))
```

I know that because datetime.now() is being called when your module is initialised and that value is being used for the default.

Hence I am not getting current date 
and solution for the same is

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

However, I am not able to add +timedelta(days=-7) for the same.

Can you please suggest how can do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)`

Comment: @jaredSmith, this is not working

Comment: Works just fine in my terminal. What do you mean "not working"?

Comment: @JaredSmith, datetime.now does not show current time but the time when module was initiated.

Comment: No, `datetime.now()` returns the date/time when you *call* it. If you only call it when the module starts, well... `now` means *now*. Call it when the module starts and store the results.

Comment: what do you want, what should happen with 'last_login_date' filed? i think its behaving correctly.

Comment: @JaredSmith, I am using GoogleAppEngine not a terminal.  I want to enter current datetime (sysdate) not the time when module starts

Comment: @VikramShinde what do you mean the "current" datetime? Current when you instantiate an instance of your class? Current when you dump some output somewhere? Also terminal, app engine, doesn't matter, python is python. The way you have it now since you're storing it in a class property it's the time when the file is parsed - 7 days. If you want when the class is instantiated (for each instance) do it in the constructor.